# Plotting coupled equations with noise modeling with Ito Process

Tags: plotting

I have a system of two coupled equations which I have to simultaneously add noise to. I am choosing to use Ito Process and in the help section of Mathematica, I did find an example of them doing it, but am unable to do it myself.

I have two variables, x and y and I'm adding noise to them simultaneously, since they are coupled and solving one requires the other. Now I want to plot them together and see what the trajectories look like.

[image]
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] Subscript[V, X] = 1; \[Alpha]1 = -1;
trajectory =  ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]  y[t] = ( ([Alpha]1*y[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2)) \[DifferentialD]t, \[DifferentialD]x[t] == (-\[Alpha]1/(x[t]^2+ y[t]^2)^(3/2) - Subscript[V, X]/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(1/2))*x[t] \[DifferentialD]t+ \[DifferentialD]w[t]}, x[t], {{x, y}, {1, 1}}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
RandomFunction[trajectory, {0, 10, 0.05}]; ListLinePlot[%, Filling -> Axis]
```

Comment: Hello ! Please, post code, not images

Comment: I've added the code. Please let me know if it's working for you. Thank you.